# Accidental "Transparent" Render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, image, image-sequence

Basically, what happened was I tried to make *A Five Nights at Freddy's* animation. I finished it, then I tried to render it. Some objects and textures were 'transparent' and others weren't for some reason.

This is how the animation came out:
[image: How The Animation came out]

Hopefully, someone can help me with this weird problem.

I made probably 3 to 5 animations and they all came out like this.

Blender Version: 3.6.5 
PC Specs: Lenovo 300e 2nd Gen Chromebook

[image]

Comment: Sorry it is a common problem currently integrated Ai into blender, that sees Fredy as conflict operation at any Lenovo hardware. For more info share your file https://blend-exchange.com/ (simpplify your file, keep just one object that still generates the issue).

Comment: @FnAfBlendurMAUn Nothing.  It just lets people download the file you uploaded so they can look at it.  Your local copy on your computer will not be messed with.

Comment: I can't reproducce your issue on my side https://imgur.com/QRe6K6R ... have you tried to rendeer file you shared with us?

Comment: Officially, Blender requires either Windows, MacOS or Linux. And other things. [Blender System Requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). How are you even able to use Blender on that Chromebook? I would suspect this issue to be inappropriate hardware

Comment: Even if you can enable the linux developer environment, ARM isn't officially supported by Blender, and you have other areas lacking in your hardware, so I wouldn't exclude the possibility of a compatibility issue.

Comment: I tried your file on different versions, and I got [this result](https://i.imgur.com/wBeaaL7.gif). But even just [from the viewport and outliner](https://i.imgur.com/ihIaDuX.png), your scene doesn't seem nearly the same as your screenshot. Do we have the same scene?

Comment: no but its ok. i just had to delete the Main Map. and keep the Model. do u mind deleting our previous comments since i kinda figured it out?